# How to Extract data from a CSV file that is only one column (name,phone,address)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a CSV file. It is only one column. Line 1 = Name. Line 2 = Phone. Line 3-5 = Address.

I have tried organizing with excel and I am lost. I am a beginner and looking to learn!

```
Chris
778-222-2445
17 Main Street
Clinton, OH
9 Miles

John
772-022-2022
411 Oxford Street
Miami, FL
15 Miles

Chris    778-222-2445    17 Main Street Clinton, OH 9 Miles
John     772-022-2022    411 Oxford Street Miami, FL 15 Miles
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

This code converts your file into flat space-separated lines

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  record = []
  for line in f:  # iterate through file
    line = line.strip() # remove useless endings
    if line: # data on line?
      record.append(line)
    else:  # empty line => next record
      if record:  # avoid printing if we had several empty lines
        print (' '.join(record))
      record = []  # create new record
  # there could be no empty line at EOF
  if record:  # avoid printing if we had several empty lines
    print (' '.join(record))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is one column then it isn't actually a CSV (that is, Comma Separated Values) file. You would need to extract each line of data and interpret what sort of data it is based on its position in the file. This would require that each set has 5 rows of data or you will have to interpret based on the data you find.

Comment: Thanks you, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `OFFSET` function can be useful here.  Assuming that your original data be in column `A`, starting at `A1`, we can use this formula for the new name column:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*6,0)
```

Then, just copy this cell (wherever it might be) down the column, to include all the names from the original data.

The logic of this formula is that it first grabs `A1`, which is the first name.  Then, the first paste would access `A1` offset by 6 rows, which lands on the second name, and so on.

You may use similar formulas for the other 4 fields in your data.

**Edit:**

Based on Ron's comments below, you might instead want to use:

```
=(ROW()-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A)
```

This formula would not need to be recalculated anytime a formula/data in your worksheet happens to change.

Comment: If you were to use `=(ROW()-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A)` you could utilize the non-volatile `INDEX` function instead.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Your Excel knowledge is way above my pay grade.  I will let your comment stand as is without an edit, because I don't understand `INDEX` that well.

Comment: `OFFSET` is a volatile function, so it recalculates whenever anything is calculated on the worksheet.  Whereas `INDEX` only recalculates when necessary, so `=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW()-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A))`.  The `COLUMNS` argument merely increases the row number being returned as you drag the formula leftward..

Comment: I get it.  I updated my question with your formula, citing you as the source.

Comment: Thank you! you guys are quick!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import csv
import xlsxwriter

# if we read f.csv we will write f.xlsx
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(sys.argv[1].replace(".csv",".xlsx"))
ws = wb.add_worksheet("WS1")    # your worksheet title here
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as csvfile:
    table = csv.reader(csvfile)
    i = 0
    # write each row from the csv file as text into the excel file
    # this may be adjusted to use 'excel types' explicitly (see xlsxwriterdoc)
    for row in table:
        ws.write_row(i, 0, row)
        i += 1
wb.close()
```

This may help you based on the each four column change the row count of the excel and increase one number for CSV row so that your next element will write the next sheet.